# How do I convert the skills/Abilities of my Fallen Aasimar 5E Character to Pathfinder?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, conversion

Hey there I was wondering how I would convert my Fallen Aasimar Character and their ability of Necrotic Shroud over to Pathfinder 1E?

Answer (score 2):

Just so we know what we are talking about, here is what Necrotic Shroud does:

> Starting at 3rd level, you can use your action to unleash the divine energy within yourself, causing your eyes to turn into pools of darkness and two skeletal, ghostly, flightless wings to sprout from your back.
> The instant you transform, other creatures within 10 feet of you that can see you must each succeed on a Charisma saving throw (DC 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier) or become frightened of you until the end of your next turn.

> Your transformation lasts for 1 minute or until you end it as a bonus action. During it, once on each of your turns, you can deal extra necrotic damage to one target when you deal damage to it with an attack or a spell. The extra necrotic damage equals your level.
> Once you use this trait, you can't use it again until you finish a long rest.

The idea of unlocking a new racial ability at 3rd level isn't common in Pathfinder 1, so this ability would be available right from the start.

PF1's Aasimars already have access to a spell-like-ability once per day (which sticks with what you want), so you would replace it for a spell that suits your needs and with a level of power on par with Daylight or the alternatives (which are all 2nd level spells).

Creation rules for races suggest not giving spells that directly deal damage or target enemies, so you would focus on the buff aspect of this spell.

From this either you pick a spell you like, or design one yourself. For this spell if there is a DC it is going to be 10 + CHA + half level (rounded up), and if you need a Caster Level it is going to be this character's level. Durations also typically last for a duration that depends of the caster level (it would be 1 round/level for you typical short-duration spell)

Spell balance in Pathfinder 1 is pretty bad, so it is hard to give you a definite answer for how powerful it should be, but a bonus of 1d6 negative energy damage to all your attacks doesn't seem too strong or too bad. It feels strong at lvl1 but remember at that time it only lasts for one round so it is actually trash unless you really need negative energy damage. Limiting it to apply only once per turn can be good if you want to avoid silly combos.

Answer (score 1):

## As a 3rd-Level Aasimar Feat

Something like the [Advanced Gathlain Magic](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Advanced%20Gathlain%20Magic) feat with tweaked prerequisites could make sense:

> **Prerequisites**: Cha 13, character level 3rd, *aasimar*.

It grants two spells usable once per day, so a similar feat granting a once per day custom spell like the ability in 5e should be reasonable.

### Converting to Pathfinder

Frightened is a bit worse in [Pathfinder 1e](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Conditions&Category=Combat), causing creatures to flee automatically from the source of fear. It might be best to preserve the original by only preventing approach. Beyond that there's a similar concept between bonus and swift actions, as well as necrotic damage and negative energy damage, which could both be more directly swapped out.

With the ability only usable once per day and requiring a feat this shouldn't severely impact balance of a campaign, and should provide a nearly identical mechanic to how the character previously played.